Build ImageMagick with XML support
I'm struggling to make ImageMagick convert images with XMP Profile.
I use such ImageMagick build in AWS lambda (python).
Here's how I assemble it:
In Dockerfile I have:
RUN yum install -y git gcc gcc-c++ cpp python-devel cpio make cmake cmake3 build-essential pkg-config automake autoconf chkconfig clang clang-libs dos2unix zlib zlib-devel zip unzip tar perl libxml2 libxml2-devel bzip2 bzip2-libs xz xz-libs pkgconfig libtool

The script which builds ImageMagick itself:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#set -e
 
cd /layer
curl https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/archive/refs/tags/7.1.1-23.tar.gz -L -o tmp-imagemagick.tar.gz
tar xf tmp-imagemagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick*
 
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/layer/build/cache/lib/pkgconfig \
  ./configure \
    CPPFLAGS=-I/layer/build/cache/include \
    LDFLAGS="-L/layer/build/cache/lib -lstdc++" \
    --disable-dependency-tracking \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --prefix=/layer/result \
    --enable-delegate-build \
    --disable-installed \
    --without-modules \
    --disable-docs \
    --with-xml=yes \
    --without-magick-plus-plus \
    --without-perl \
    --without-x \
    --disable-openmp
make clean
make all
make install
ldconfig -v /usr/local/lib
ldconfig -v /usr/lib64

I try to execute command: ./magick convert myImage.jpeg output.json (which works OK with images without XMP Profile)
As a result I get an error:
libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please advise

Please click [edit] and show output from echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and find / -name libxml2.so.2 2> /dev/null

First, with IM 7 use magick, not magick convert. Second what is your IM version and what does magick -version show for your delegates. Does it list xml?  Third post an example image for which you are having this issue.
